# My website is reported to belong to "Japan" on Alexa's ranking

Tags: domains, ranking, alexa

I'm the owner of [Thought Results](http://www.thoughtresults.com), which is a newbie I just started. I'm an Iranian guy. But when I see Alexa's ranking, it says that my website belongs to Japan. Also Visualize Traffic reports the same thing. You can check at:

http://www.alexa.com/search?q=thoughtresults.com
http://visualizetraffic.com/update.php?q=thoughtresults.com

In spite of this, I'm still able to login to almost every place, including database, control panel, domain tools, etc.

What does this mean? Am I hacked by somebody? Has somebody stolen my domain name?

Comment: According to NetCraft, you're hosted out of the UK on a Windows 2008 server owned by eUKhost LTD. [link](http://toolbar.netcraft.com/site_report?url=http://www.thoughtresults.com) For some reason, Alexa and visualizetraffic are reporting that all the incoming visitors to your website are coming from Japan. Since Alexa has always been suspect in my books, if you really want to know where your traffic is coming from, sign up with Google Analytics to find what's really happening. As to whether you've been hacked, none of the above would tell you that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click through the traffic rank number, the [next screen](http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/thoughtresults.com) points out that apparently a large portion of your traffic *comes from* Japan, not that your site "belongs" to it; there's no such thing.

This is presumably why they showed that information on the other screen(in a rather opaque and poorly-designed way). Whether or not that's actually true is for you to determine based on your own stats. Keep in mind most people consider Alexa to be pretty much worthless and the numbers it presents highly questionable.